# Getting System.Object[] output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote this quick script to retrieve information about a bunch of servers. When I run on my windows 7 (ps v2) host I get all the correct results. However, When I run on Server 2008 r2 (ps v2) I get **System.Object[]** for all the queries below. I have a bunch of other queries as well but they all work fine, just these ones I am getting this problem. Whats going on?

```
$ArrComputers = "localhost"
$OutputLog = ".\output.csv" 
$NotRespondingLog = ".\notresponding.txt" 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
Clear-Host

$data = ForEach ($Computer in $ArrComputers)  {
try{

    $ipAdd          = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName .)| select ipaddress
    $MacAdd         = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName .)| Select MacAddress
    $DefGateway     = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName .)| Select DefaultIPGateway   
    $DNSServ        = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName .)| Select DNSServerSearchOrder 
    $CPUname        = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName .)| Select name
    $processorinfo = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName .)| Select NumberOfCores
    $processorinfo2 = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName .)| Select NumberOfLogicalProcessors

$memory = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer |
Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum |
select @{N="r"; E={[math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2)}}


}catch{
    $Computer | Out-File -FilePath $NotRespondingLog -Append -Encoding UTF8
    continue    
}

$props = @{


'IPAddress'      = $ipAdd
'MacAddress'     = $MacAdd
'DefaultIPGateway'= $DefGateway
'DNSServerSearchOrder' = $DNSServ
'cpuName'        = $CPUname
'Cores'          = $processorinfo
'logicalcores'   = $processorinfo2
' Memory'         =  $memory


} 
New-object -type PSCustomObject -Property $Props
} 

$Data | export-csv -notypeinformation $outputlog
```

Comment: I added the string below to $props and it worked                                                                                               'IPAddress'      = ($ipadd | select -ExpandProperty ipaddress) -join "," this is because if the computer has more than 1 interface,you get empty string. I found the answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/55734274-634d-465e-a655-03f7f404f349/systemstring-in-output-of-converttohtml-when-im-expecting-a-regular-string-data?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 0):

So the issue what you are facing: Powershell is returning the $data as Key=Value or hashtable format but as an object. So when you are inserting the same as CSV , then  it is returning it as Object. So what you can do is you can convert the data to JSON format and you can insert the same. Else you can use Arraylist and insert all the values there. In that case it will accept the key-value pair mapping.

Hope it helps

Comment: But this works for other queries like $OS             = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

Comment: I will modify the script and will post it then.. YOu dont need to use so many things actually if you really bother about the data

Comment: Thank you so much Ranadip, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me a completely different output.

Comment: @NebelzCheez : Give me sometime to sit for it. Probably by this weekend I can make it. I just tweaked a little bit and picked the first array Index.

Comment: Yes please! I am still getting same error with DefaultIpAddress and DNSServerSearchOrder. The rest seemed to work fine after that -join statement

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the headers from the select query and created an array list with the custom object created in the loop and it will add each details from server to server and will append in the array list separately. I hope this helps you.

```
$ArrComputers = "localhost"
$OutputLog = ".\output.csv" 
$NotRespondingLog = ".\notresponding.txt" 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
Clear-Host
$Global:arraylist= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$data = ForEach ($Computer in $ArrComputers)  {
try{

    $ipAdd          = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $Computer)| select ipaddress
    $MacAdd         = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $Computer)| Select MacAddress
    $DefGateway     = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $Computer)| Select DefaultIPGateway   
    $DNSServ        = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $Computer)| Select DNSServerSearchOrder 
    $CPUname        = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $Computer)| Select name
    $processorinfo = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $Computer)| Select NumberOfCores
    $processorinfo2 = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $Computer)| Select NumberOfLogicalProcessors

$memory = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer |
Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum |
select @{N="r"; E={[math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2)}}
$props =[PSCustomObject]@{


'IPAddress'      = $ipAdd.ipaddress[0]
'MacAddress'     = $MacAdd.MacAddress
'DefaultIPGateway'= $DefGateway.DefaultIPGateway[0]
'DNSServerSearchOrder' = $DNSServ.DNSServerSearchOrder[0]
'cpuName'        = $CPUname.name
'Cores'          = $processorinfo.NumberOfCores
'logicalcores'   = $processorinfo2.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
' Memory'         =  $memory.r


}
$arraylist.Add($props)
}catch{
    $Computer | Out-File -FilePath $NotRespondingLog -Append -Encoding UTF8
    continue    
}


} 

$arraylist | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $OutputLog -Force
```